# How do I unit test downloading a file using Jasmine (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have an Angular 6 app that has an "export to CSV" button that when clicked, runs a method on the component that generates the CSV text to be downloaded. The file is then downloaded with the following code:

```
const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
tempLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
tempLink.target = '_blank';
tempLink.download = 'export.csv';
tempLink.click();
```

How would I unit test clicking the "Export to CSV" button without triggering an actual download?

Would the only approach be to create the link in the HTML (not dynamically) and then have a Jasmine spy on the click event of the link?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [Jasmine spy functions](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy.html) (spyOn, spyOnProperty, jasmine.createSpy, jasmine.createSpyObj) in combination with the [and methods](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/Spy_and.html) to spy on and mock behavior.

In this case you can mock `document.createElement()` to return a spy object that you can use to verify that the correct properties get set and `click()` gets called.

Here is a working example:

---

example.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: '<div><button (click)="download()">Download Csv</button></div>'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  download() {
    const csvContent = this.generateCsv();
    const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    tempLink.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
    tempLink.target = '_blank';
    tempLink.download = 'export.csv';
    tempLink.click();
  }

  private generateCsv() {
    return 'ID,Name\n1,abc\n2,def\n';
  }

}
```

---

example.component.spec.ts

```
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';

describe('ExampleComponent', () => {

  it('should download the csv file', () => {
    // create spy object with a click() method
    const spyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj('a', ['click']);
    // spy on document.createElement() and return the spy object
    spyOn(document, 'createElement').and.returnValue(spyObj);

    const comp = new ExampleComponent();
    comp.download();

    expect(document.createElement).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(document.createElement).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a');

    expect(spyObj.href).toBe('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,ID,Name%0A1,abc%0A2,def%0A');
    expect(spyObj.target).toBe('_blank');
    expect(spyObj.download).toBe('export.csv');
    expect(spyObj.click).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(spyObj.click).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });

});
```

Comment: @mprahl awesome! 

Comment: I get "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.". Any ideas?

Comment: @MitchellBrooks I had the same error, and in my case it was because I had a document.body.appendChild in the function I was testing. I solved by adding a `spyOn(document["body"], 'appendChild');`.